# specs2 After method runs before the example

Tags: scala, testing, specs2

I have the following test:

```
class Foo extends mutable.SpecificationWithJUnit {
sequential

"this example should run before the 'After' method" in new Context {
    bar must beSome
}

class Context extends mutable.BeforeAfter with mutable.Around {

  override def apply[T : AsResult](a: =>T): Result = {
  lazy val result = super[Around].apply(a)
  super[BeforeAfter].apply(result)
  }

  override def delayedInit(x: => Unit): Unit = around { try { before; x; Success() } finally { after }}

  @Resource var barReader : BarReader = _

  val bar = barReader.someBar

  override def before : Any = { //some stuff}

  def after: Any = {
    bar = None
  }

  override def around[T : AsResult](t: =>T) = {
     //spring context injection logic
     AsResult.effectively(t)
  }

  }
}
}
```

I expect this test to pass but in reality what happens is that because of the delayed init, the after runs before the example. If I change the Context to a trait I lose the delayed init functionality. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Edited:
This example will throw an NPE when the Context is a trait. What I expect to happen is that because of the delayed-init, the Context's constructor, which consequentially means the barReader.someBar will run only after the barReader has been injected.

Thanks
Netta

Comment: Your updated example seems over-complicated to me. Can you try something like this: https://gist.github.com/etorreborre/8529040

Comment: doesn't work. The Context's constructor runs before the injection occurs.

Comment: actually, your example will work cause of the lazy val. Mine doesn't because the val isn't lazy and I'm trying to avoid making it so.

Comment: Why don't you want the val to be lazy?

Comment: Because it's annoying to mark everything as lazy and then have a trigger somewhere. Also, I think it kind of defeats the purpose of the delayed init method.

Comment: Then I don't know how to do that :-(

Comment: You don't think it's a bug that delayed init doesn't work as expected within the specs2 framework?

Comment: DelayedInit has various edge cases. It was even suggested that it should be removed. I protested precisely because it's needed in specs2 but I suspect that we need to keep it's usage simple as suggested in my gist.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Simple answer, looks like this can't be done.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a trait instead of a class for `Context`. If you use a class, `delayedInit` (hence `after`) will be triggered twice. Once for the body of the `Context` class and another time for the body of the anonymous class `new Context`. With a trait you don't get such a behavior:

```
class Foo extends mutable.SpecificationWithJUnit {
  sequential

  "this example should run before the 'After' method" in new Context {
    bar must beSome
  }

  trait Context extends mutable.After {
    var bar : Option[String] = Some("bar")

    def after: Any = bar = None
  }
}
```

Comment: Taken from the scala documentation (http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.DelayedInit) - "Classes and objects (but note, not traits) inheriting the DelayedInit marker trait will have their initialization code rewritten as follows: code becomes delayedInit(code)". Which from my understanding means that the delayedInit code will not work unless the Context is defined as a class.
I'll alter the above example so to emphasize the problem a bit better.

Comment: Right but when you write `new Context` you create an anonymous class.

Comment: Good point. However something still falls apart. I'll try to tweak my example to better emphasize the problem when things get a little more complicated.