# Specs2: Using Outside with After

Tags: specs2

I'm trying to write a mutable Spec that has a value passed in by a Scope. I also need to be able to do some cleanup after each test runs. Following the documentation, I tried using an [Outside](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Outside) combined with an [After](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#In+a+mutable+specification) but got mixed results.

Is the fifth example the correct approach for this or am I missing something basic?

```scala
import org.specs2.mutable.{After, Specification}
import org.specs2.specification.Outside

class ExampleSpec extends Specification {
  "Tests using Outside and After" >> {
    "#1 doesn't run the after" in c1() {
      (m: String) => {
        println("Running test 1.")
        success
      }
    }
    "#2 doesn't actually run the test" in new c2() {
      (m: String) => {
        println("Running test 2.")
        failure
      }
    }
    "#3 doesn't run the after" in (new t3{}) {
      (m: String) => {
        println("Running test 3.")
        success
      }
    }
    "#4 doesn't actually run the test" in new t4 {
      (m: String) => {
        println("Running test 4.")
        failure
      }
    }
    "#5 works, but is it the right way?" in new t5 {
      val sessionKey = outside // The test would have to call outside?
      println("Running test 5.")
      success
    }
  }

  trait common extends Outside[String] with After {
    def name: String
    def outside = "Used by the real test."
    def after = println("After for " + name)
  }
  case class c1() extends common { def name = "c1" }
  case class c2() extends common { def name = "c2" }
  trait t3 extends common { def name = "t3" }
  trait t4 extends common { def name = "t4" }
  trait t5 extends common { def name = "t5" }
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
Running test 1.
After for c2
Running test 3.
After for t4
Running test 5.
After for t5
[info] ExampleSpec
[info] 
[info] Tests using Outside and After
[info] + #1 doesn't run the after
[info] + #2 doesn't actually run the test
[info] + #3 doesn't run the after
[info] + #4 doesn't actually run the test
[info] + #5 works, but is it the right way?
[info] 
[info] Total for specification ExampleSpec
[info] Finished in 19 ms
[info] 5 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
```

Note: Per Eric's comments to [Question 21154941](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154941/specs2-after-method-runs-before-the-example), I realize tests 1 and 2 are not the correct approach. I put them here to be exhaustive and because at other times, you can use case classes for contexts/variable isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the simplest thing to do is to use the `org.specs2.specification.FixtureExample` trait:

```
class ExampleSpec extends Specification with FixtureExample[F] {
  "Tests using a fixture" >> {
    "you can use the fixture values" in { f: F =>
      println("Running test 1 with "+f.sessionKey)
      success
    }
    "there is cleanup after each example" in { f: F =>
      success
    }
  }

  def fixture[R : AsResult](f: F => R): Result = {
     try AsResult(f(F()))
     finally cleanup
  }

  def cleanup = println("cleanup")
}

case class F(sessionKey: String = "key")
```

Comment: Thanks, Eric. That should put me on the right track.